# Is it possible to get the URL of the image from the image_pack_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

### Background

In the default `packs/application.js` file, you're greeted with the following comments

```
// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

Using these comments, I created the following JavaScript functions to include everything in `app/assets/images`

```
const images = require.context('../../assets/images', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

I can call the `image_pack_tag` helper like so:

```
<%= image_pack_tag 'media/images/logo.svg' %>
```

However, I have an HTML tag where I need to add a background. For now, it looks like so:

```
<section class="bg-cover" style="background-image: url(assets/img/covers/cover.jpg);">
```

### Question

Is there a way for me to extract the path of the image from the `image_pack_tag` so that I can do this:

```
<section class="bg-cover" style="background-image: url(<%= image_pack_tag_url 'media/covers/cover.jpg' %>);">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `asset_pack_path` helper. In your situation, you want to use:

```
asset_pack_path 'media/covers/cover.jpg'
```

In the background attribute, that becomes:

```
<section class="bg-cover" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_pack_path 'media/covers/cover.jpg' %>);">
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it only worked with `asset_pack_url`:

[method on github](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/5780a0a9b969560596e3a0ace2398c7e291f9c0b/lib/webpacker/helper.rb#L37)

so something along `asset_pack_url "static/some_image.webp"` regarding your definition in manifest.json